# Задержка анимации при при наведенном hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Нужно сделать анимацию, что бы при наведении на блок поднималась нижняя полоска заливая его фоном. НО: что бы она не опускалась до того момента, как мышка уйдет за пределы блока.

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/77ehft5p/)

html

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-line"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.box {
width:300px;
height: 170px;
border:1px solid black;
position:relative;
}

.box-line {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
background-color: silver;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

jquery

```
$(".box").hover(function() {

    $(".box-line").animate({height: "100%"}, 500, function() {

        $(".box-line").animate({height: "50px"})

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще на чистом css

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height: 170px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}

.box-line {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transition: .5s height;
}
.box:hover .box-line{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Блин точно я и забыл))) спасибо) но все же, оставлю вопрос открытым по решению на javascript